# Why does my AE Crafting System lose its jobs when I'm no longer present?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

Sometimes, uncommonly, my AE Crafting System, if loaded with a job that takes a long time, stops working, for seemingly no reason, but only when I'm not around. I've triple checked my chunk loaders, and everything neccesary for the network to run is chunk loaded. (I have a 100 chunk square area chunkloaded around my base) I have plenty of mats for everything, and the mats that are not stored in my AE network are also chunk loaded.  All the machines the MAC uses to craft with are chunk loaded. My power supply is chunk loaded. When I return to the interface after such a failed job, the Crafting Monitor is empty, showing no current jobs or missing mats.

What am I missing that might be causing this?

Disclaimers:

- The AE Network is not being changed by anything to my knowledge, that is, I'm 100% sure nothing is automated to place any AE blocks or remove any.
- My base is centered in an area that has 4 chunkloaders, each keeping 25 chunks loaded, strategically placed so that they each cover their own quadrant of a square. This totals a 100 Chunk Square Area that's constantly loaded, and nothing in my network is even close to the border.
- I have no Quantum Bridge's nor do I have any Dark Cables.
- Since paying attention to the issue, I can confirm this happens everytime I logoff, or leave the area of my base. This would suggest that it's a Chunkloading issue, however, I'm not at all sure how that could be possible given my 2nd Disclaimer...

[image: Area Four]

[image: Area Three]

[image: Area Two]

[image: Area One]

You can see in each of these photo's my floating chunkloader. If streaming was an option I could show a video of me walking the chunk lines and confirming that each of my chunk loaders is in the proper place to keep the entire area loaded. Each Chunkloader manages a 25 chunk quarter section of a 100 chunk square. (as I've already said)

You may have noticed the cobblestone border around my area, that marks where the chunkloading ends, and I'm 100% sure I have no ME-anything that crosses any of the borders.

[image: Chunk Proof]

Here I have turned on all 4 chunkloader's 'show lasers option', and took a screenshot of the CENTER of the square of my chunkloaded area, you can see the 4 lasers from each chunkloader converging on the center chunk borderline, this proves there are no 'gaps' in the chunkloading.

**Edit: I have determined that this is almost certainly a chunkloading issue, as the other night before I logged off, I bred my cows, but when I logged back in, over 8 hours later, some cows were still baby cows. I have since broken and replaced all my chunkloaders, thinking perhaps they were bugged and not working even though they were properly placed. The issue remains however.**

**Edit2: I have come as close to being sure as I can be, reduplicating the issue just to prove I fixed it isn't worth it.(I've since wiped the server)  But, for what it's worth, it seems chicken-chunks-chunk-loaders are partially bugged. (we knew this but not to the exact extent.) Some of the chunks were not always properly loaded despite being chunkloaded causing the system to reset when I left the area. Using many spotloaders rather than few chunkloaders seems to fix the chunkloading bug issue. If at all possible also attempt to load the chunks using a chunk loading device that isn't from Chicken chunks, such as a World Anchor or Dimensional Anchor.**

Comment: Usually crafting jobs disappearing is caused by having your AE network reset, which happens when there is a change to the network. Could it be that any part of your AE network isn't chunkloaded?

Comment: or a dark cable being toggled? a quantum bridge getting unpowered/repowered?

Comment: I am surprised no one has answered this yet.

Comment: @RavenM your suprised and I'm upset. I really want this answered.

Comment: Are there many other areas chunkloaded? A couple quarries, a pump in the nether,... things like that? How many other chunkloaders do you have?

Comment: I have two quarries that are not always running, and probably 2-3 chunkloaders in my lava age, and the 4 chunk loaders mentioned in this question but that should be about it for *me* on chunk loaders. I cant speak for others... why?

Comment: Because I've had an issue before where two of my quarries didn't chunkload themself. It was caused by a limit in one of the config files. There is a limit to the area one player is allowed to chunkload, and a limit to the amount of chunkloaders one can use for chunkloading IIRC. One other question: why do you use 4 chunkloaders with each an area of ~25 chunks instead of one chunkloader with an area of ~100 chunks?

Comment: @Arperum Because if I did 1 chunkloader loading 100 chunks it wouldnt cover a square area as it's an even number, You can only put a chunkloader in the 'center chucnk' of an odd number of chunks. I'm going to look up this config idea, you may be on to something.

Comment: @Arperum I have found similar settings in the chicken chunks and forge configs, changed them to better ensure this isn't the problem, and my problem persists. Are there other configs I'm missing?

Comment: it is a bug, it happens alot to me too

Comment: I have come as close to being sure as I can be without being sure enough to post as an answer as reduplicating the issue (ive since wiped the server) just to prove I fixed it isn't worth it. But for what its worth it seems chunk loaders are partially bugged. (we knew this but not to the exact extent.) Some of the chunks were not always properly loaded despite being chunkloaded causing the system to reset when I left the area. Using many spotloaders rather than few chunkloaders **seems** to fix the chunkloading bug issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this bug before in FTB Unleashed. Be sure to update AE as recent as you can without changing to 1.6 (Unhinged is 1.5) from the author's download site; the mod author is very good about releasing frequent updates and bugfixes. I think this has to do with the crafting monitor itself. I don't believe I found a permanent solution when I had this, but I did find a workaround. Try hooking up all parts of your ME network to go through a single ME Cable. When it decides to stop building, just break and replace the cable. All build progress will be lost, but the materials used and created so far are kept.

Comment: Please don't point people to a different forum; the whole point of Arqade is to help people, not, "Go here if none of this helps."

Comment: @Frank He does have a point, though; if it *is* a bug (which it very well may be), then the mod authors would probably like to know about it. There's a difference between "You should ask here for help" and "If all else fails, this might be a bug. You can report it here."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: I just removed a part of my assembler chamber and replaced it. This was a good easy fix for me and I hope this helps anyone in the future, if all of the above doesn't work.